# HOW to implement backend with "EXPRESS" and frontend with "NUXT.JS"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, nuxtjs

I am new at web development and saying sorry for this question. THE thing is that i have done a serverside with Express and connected to MongoDB, have already established the connection where i can insert, select, delete information, but don't know how to make Frontend side  with NUXT.JS, i want to put 4 buttons in frontend which will be select, insert, delete buttons . Here is my backend:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// create express app
const app = express();

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// Configuring the database
const dbConfig = require('./config/database.config.js');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// Connecting to the database
mongoose.connect(dbConfig.url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully connected to the database");    
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Could not connect to the database. Exiting now...', err);
    process.exit();
}); 
// define a simple route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({"message": "Welcome to EasyNotes application. Take notes quickly. Organize and keep track of all your notes."});
});

// Require Notes routes
require('./app/routes/note.routes.js')(app);
// listen for requests
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is listening on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: I think this github repo will help you
https://github.com/nuxt-community/express-template